# What would cause some SSNs to be missing a single digit if the column ssn_num is of type integer?

Tags: sql, string, types

What would cause some SSNs to be missing a single digit if the column ssn_num is of type integer? I would have chosen it to be of type String, but curious as to what could cause it to leave out single digit

I tried looking up various scenarios in which SSNs were stored as type int, but didn't really find anything useful

Answer (score 3):

The most common scenario for truncation here would be if the SSN itself begins with a leading `0` - integers in most all modern RDMBS' won't retain information about leading zeroes, as they are mathematically immaterial.

SSNs aren't integers, and shouldn't be stored as such.

Comment: Ahh ok than you @esqew.

Comment: `and shouldn't be stored as such.`  ... and hopefully aren't stored in plain text either

Comment: @SOS A good point, and more broadly unless they fall under one of the 20-someodd "approved" uses for SSNs (for U.S. SSNs specifically), they really shouldn't be stored at all. I considered adding a paragraph about that to the answer, but ultimately deemed it much too far outside the scope of the question to add it.